# How to parse JSON with key as number, returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read the data from my json with below format but it results with undefined

My JSON as below

```
{
    "1": "A",
    "2": "B",
    "3": "C",
    "4": "D",
    "5": "E",
    "6": "F",
    "key":"pair"    
}
```

I'm parsing as below

```
rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
data = JSON.parse(rawdata);
console.log(data.1) //returns undefined. I tried parsing 1 to String but resulted same.
console.log(data.key) //returns pair
```

Comment: You can use `[]` notation to get values in an object like `data["1"]`

Comment: @Srinu I tried with bracket notation as mentioned but it returned 'undefined'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use dot notation to access an object's property if that property's name starts with a number.

To get a the property you'll need to use square bracket notation:

```js
let o = JSON.parse(`{
    "1": "A",
    "2": "B",
    "3": "C",
    "4": "D",
    "5": "E",
    "6": "F",
    "key":"pair"    
}`);

console.log(o['1']);
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) to access a value, the property key must be a valid identifier

> In this code, property must be a valid JavaScript identifier, i.e. a
>   sequence of alphanumerical characters, also including the underscore
>   ("_") and dollar sign ("$"), that cannot start with a number. For
>   example, object.$1 is valid, while object.1 is not.

You can use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) in this case

```
obj['1']
```

Spec: [Property Accessors](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-property-accessors)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `rawdata = fs.readFileSync('./data.json');`
This tells the script the `data.json` file is in the same folder as it.
And then use `.data['1']` to get the value.